# Could somebody explain how is it possible that the const tags array in createTags can be modified like this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constants

It doesn't make sense to me that i can assign the input character by character to the tags array. createTags will execute right after every keyup event, how does it remember earlier inputs and how can i modify constant array?

```
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    createTags(e.target.value)
})

const createTags = (input) => {
    const tags = input.split(',').filter(tag => tag.trim() !== '').map(tag => tag.trim())
    console.log(tags)
}
```

Output:

```
["t"]
["te"]
["tes"]
["test"]
["test"]
["test", "t"]
["test", "te"]
["test", "tes"]
["test", "test"]
["test", "test"]
```

Comment: why you think `it remember earlier inputs and how can i modify constant array?`

Comment: `e.target.value` is all text of the `textarea`, so, `createTags` function no need remember last value

Comment: It doesn't remember the old inputs, the inputs are just saved in the `textarea`. And whenever you put new content there, it re-runs the function with new data.

Comment: `const tags` is never modified.

Comment: Thank you all. I misunderstood that the `e.target.value` part. @MERN